# Cannot run ReCaptcha through HTMLUnit

Tags: java, recaptcha, htmlunit

All!

For whatsoever reason, I cannot access the reCaptcha dialog when using HTMLUnit. There is an old question regarding an inability to click on the checkbox, and I've solved that. However, after I click it, I get an alert stating "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again." and the dialog doesn't load properly. I can't figure what would be preventing the connection.

Here is an the portion of my code meant to run the javascript:

```
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("https://my_website.xyz/login");
HtmlPage innerCaptchaPage = (HtmlPage) page.getFrames().get(0).getEnclosedPage();


HtmlElement checkbox = innerCaptchaPage.getBody().getElementsByAttribute("div", "class", "recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark").get(0);

HtmlPage clickPage = checkbox.click();
JavaScriptJobManager
        mainManager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager(),
        subManager = clickPage.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager()
;


int count;
do {

  int mainCount, subCount;
  mainCount = mainManager.getJobCount();
  subCount = subManager.getJobCount();

  count = mainCount + subCount;

  System.out.printf("Awaiting %d javascript job(s)... (%d / %d)\n", count, mainCount, subCount);

  mainManager.waitForJobs(5_000);
  subManager.waitForJobs(5_000);

} while (count > 0);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve the problem?